# Inserting column value, into XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, insert, sql-update

I have a table called [catcot] that has a 'name' column and an 'xml' column.

'name' is a varchar and 'xml' is of type XML

Currently the 'xml' column contains

```
<Cat>
  <Temp>.html</Temp>
</Cat>
```

I need to insert the value in column 'name' just before the '.html'

Is this possible? I have tried a general update however it doesn't seem to accept XML content.

Here is the update I tried:

```
UPDATE [db].[catcot]
SET xml = '<Cat><Temp>' + name + '.html</Temp></Cat>'
WHERE id = 24
```

Which resulted in

```
XML parsing: line 1, character 67, illegal name character
```

Comment: could post your update sentence?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Matt The reason for your problem *XML parsing: line 1, character 67, illegal name character* is very probably bound to illegal characters within `name`. That's why you should not build XML on string-level. Just imagine a name like `Matt & Friends` or names including special/foreign characters. The concatenated string will be something like `<Cat><Temp>Matt & Friends</Temp></Cat>`, which is not allowed...

Comment: @Matt - you want to append the `name` or totally replace the `<Temp>` node value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with an updateable CTE:

```
DECLARE @catcot TABLE(name VARCHAR(100),TheXml XML);
INSERT INTO @catcot VALUES
 ('test1','<Cat><Temp>.html</Temp></Cat>')
,('test2','<Cat><Temp>.html</Temp></Cat>');

WITH updateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT TheXml
          ,(SELECT name AS Temp FOR XML PATH('Cat')) AS NewXml
    FROM @catcot
)
UPDATE updateableCTE SET TheXml=NewXml;

SELECT * FROM @catcot;
```

### Important!

You should **never** create XML via string concatenation!